# Xamarin Forms. Load View from ViewModel after button click

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms

How can this be done?
I have been able to implement this using xaml and like so. 
How would i do this using the `ViewModel` pattern instead?

View.xaml

```
<Button Margin="50,0,20,20" FontSize="Large" Text="Test" Clicked="Button_Clicked">
                </Button>
```

View.cs

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Get_LessonViewAsync();            
}

private async void Get_LessonViewAsync()
{
    var view = new LessonView();
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(view);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In xaml you bind using the Command attribute:

```
<Button Margin="50,0,20,20" FontSize="Large" Text="Test" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"></Button>
```

In your ViewModel:

```
public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; private set; }
public ICommand GoLeftCommand { get; private set; }     
public ICommand GoRightCommand { get; private set; }     

public DemoViewModel ()
{
    ...
    ButtonCommand = new Command (() => {
            var view = new LessonView();
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(view);
        });
    GoLeftCommand = new Command (() => {
            var view = new LeftView();
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(view);
        });
    GoRightCommand = new Command (() => {
            var view = new RightView();
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(view);
        });
}
```

Snippets from: https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/ by David Britch

Comment: Thanks, one more question. If i were to implement ICommand Interface. Like so, public void Execute(object parameter){} How would i know which command was fired

Comment: If i understand your question correct, you would have one Property for each command.